# How to change font size and color of legendbox entries and chart title

Tags: lightningchart

I add the chart title like below

```
 chart[unique].setTitle(nn).setPadding({
        bottom: -2,
        right: -2,
        top: -36,
        left: -2
    }).setMouseInteractions(false);
```

How do I set the font size? I tried `setFont((font) => font.setSize(12))`, but it's not working.

Also I am not able to add it to legendBox:

```
legendBox["axis"].add(line[name], undefined, ' ').setText(entryname);
```

I want to set font size and color for chart title and legendbox entries or full legendbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ChartXY title font](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/chartxy.html#settitlefont)

LegendBox title and entries can be styled by methods of the [LegendBox Builder](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/interfaces/uilegendboxbuilder.html) (`setTitle`, `setEntry`):

```
const legendBox = ChartXY.addLegendBox(
    LegendBoxBuilders.VerticalLegendBox
        .setTitle((title) => title
            .setFont((font) => font.setFamily('monospace'))
        )
        .setEntry((entry) => entry
            .setFont((font) => font.setSize(10).setStyle('italic'))
        ),
)
```

EDIT

[ChartXY title color](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/chartxy.html#settitlefillstyle)

Comment: Thank you , still not able to change chart title color